# Does the Qt Visual Studio plugin support Qbs based projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Is there a way to integrate a Qt Creator QBS (not qmake) project with Visual Studio? The Qt addon only supports qmake projects.

Comment: it's not clear what your question is, please state it clearly!

Comment: Should be clear now.

Comment: Bumping question...